# What's a good CSS button framework for Compass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compass-sass

I'd like to be able to configure colors, gradients, etc..

Answer (score 8):

I'd check out the following:

- [Fancy Buttons](http://brandonmathis.com/projects/fancy-buttons/)
- [Multi-Line Buttons](http://wiseheartdesign.com/articles/2010/10/19/multi-line-buttons-with-compass-sass-and-css3/)
- [Stylish Buttons](http://css3-buttons.heroku.com/)
- [Button Tutorial](http://drewyeaton.com/post/511108336/beautiful-buttons-with-sass-math)

Maybe one of these will help you, if not, [make your own button library](http://chriseppstein.github.com/blog/2010/10/21/compass-extensions-are-easy/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using fancy-buttons sass plugin: https://github.com/imathis/fancy-buttons
Its fully customizable.

Answer (score 1):

[Sassy Buttons](http://jaredhardy.com/sassy-buttons/) is another Compass extension to create CSS3-buttons (with proper fallbacks for older browsers). It's highly configurable and offers various gradient-, text- and button-styles out of the box.